# Looking for easy, unintrusive, free entry user survey

Tags: magento1.9.3

I'm asking for this specifically for a Magento installation, so that magento specific solutions could potentially solve this (i.e. extensions).

I'd like to do user surveys, but I find the way Magento does it pretty heavy handed. On the one hand, the structure is pretty rigid, on the other hand the answers must be specified beforehand.

What I'd like to do is ask probably one simple question, where I'm only interested in the answer. No other data necessary. Something like this:

```
Q: If you had one wish for THISSITE, what would it be?
A: <a simple text field, answer finalized through the enter key or through leaving the field>
```

The answers would need to go somewhere, I'd accept even a text file with all answers, one after the other.

Something like [Stomt](https://www.stomt.com/) is close, but it's linked as a social network/tell others kind of service, which is more for the social interaction and less for the site owner.